# How do I properly initiate this class so that on mouseleave my drop-down will slide up?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I finally got this drop-down to animate and behave the way I want it to, but I have one little bug that makes it so that on the initial mouseleave of a drop-down trigger will not cause the drop-down to slide up but instead just freezes in place. Other than that, I'm a pretty new programmer so if anyone has some tips on how to make this run cleaner or make my code more efficient I always love to get professional criticism on my code. Thanks.

```
     /** Mega DropDown **/
/* Determine if the user is hovering over the trigger for more than .5sec and if there is already a drop-down menu showing. 
If there is then modify the containing elements height to match the new contained elements and if not then set the 
containing element to the correct height */
$(".cataDropDown").mouseenter(function () {
    $this = $(this); //use currently selected ".cataDropdown"

    var EleHt = ($this.children('ul').height()) + 29; //Get height of contained elements for slide event
    var count = 0;
    var onHoverTimer = setInterval(function () {
        count += 1; //setInterval for hover timer

        //If User hovers over trigger for more than .5 seconds - 
        if (count >= 1) {
            clearInterval(onHoverTimer); //Clear counter
            onHoverTimer = setInterval(300);

            $(".cataDropDown").children('ul').animate({ opacity: '0' }, 200).hide(); //Give contained elements dimension but keep hidden with opacity property
            $this.children('ul').show().css('opacity', '0'); //Give contained elements dimension but keep hidden with opacity property
            $this.parents('div#menuContainer').stop(true, false).animate({ height: EleHt }, 400); //Open container to height of contained elements
            $this.children('ul').stop(true, true).animate({ opacity: '1' }, 200); //show child elements (menu)
            $this.addClass('menu-active') //add class "menu-active" to test if the drop-down is currently open
        }
    }, 300);

    $(".cataDropDown").mouseleave(function () {
        clearInterval(onHoverTimer); //Clear counter to prevent opening the menu by accident
        onHoverTimer = setInterval(300);

        if (!$this.hasClass('menu-active')) {
            $(".cataDropDown").removeClass('menu-active');
            $this.parents('div#menuContainer').animate({ height: '27px' }, 400);
            $('.cataDropDown > ul').stop().animate({ opacity: '0' }, 200, function () {
                $(this).hide();
            });
        } else {
            $this.parents('div#menuContainer').stop(true, false).animate({ height: EleHt }, 200);
            $this.removeClass('menu-active');
            //window.console && console.log(EleHt);
        }
    });
});
```

edit: JSFiddle as requested - http://jsfiddle.net/hUtAp/8/

Comment: Please also share your HTML, preferably inside a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Ok, I added a JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/hUtAp/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code within your `mouseleave()` handler is to blame.  Try [this simplified version](http://jsfiddle.net/HUDjh/2/):

```
 $(".cataDropDown").mouseleave(function () {

     clearInterval(onHoverTimer); //Clear counter to prevent opening the menu by accident
     onHoverTimer = setInterval(300);

     $(".cataDropDown").removeClass('menu-active');
     $this.parents('div#menuContainer').stop().animate({
         height: '27px'
     }, 500);
     $('.cataDropDown > ul').stop().animate({
         opacity: '0'
     }, 200, function () {
         $(this).hide();
     });
 });
```